# Trigger.io 1.4 not reliably firing connectionStateChange on app startup

Tags: android, trigger.io

Using platform 1.4.9 with Android 3.2 on a Motorola xyboard (Xoom 2), the connectionStateChange listener is not firing when disconnected from the internet on the initial app startup. I've tested in both airplane mode and with Wifi off. It does however fire properly when there is an active connection upon app startup.

Comment: App startup is different than appResumed right?  Did you try using the appResumed event handler?

Comment: I didn't, but the problem is most crucial on the first time the app is run to sync a bunch of data from Parse. The docs specifically say they guarantee it will be fired at least once on app startup, however that only happens when the device has an active connection on startup. With no connection, that event never fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - we should be firing that event and we're not: targeting a fix deployed next week.

Our bad!

Comment: Actually, we'll have it deployed by the end of this week.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up solving this with a setTimeout hack but will resort to listening for that event when fix is deployed.

Comment: v1.4.12 of the Forge platform includes a fix for this: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-12